# Problemas con ssl en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, socket, ssl

Hola soy nuevo en nodejs, estoy haciendo un proyecto con socket.io y necesito que se conecte de forma segura con https,  pero no logro hacer que funcione el certificado SSL.

esto es lo que tengo:

```
var fs =    require('fs');
    var socket  = require('socket.io' );//forma de conectarse
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/servidor.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/servidor.crt'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/sca.server1.crt')
    };
    var express = require( 'express');
    var app= express();
    var server  = require( 'https' ).createServer(options ,app );///tipo de conexion
    var io      = socket.listen( server );//establecer canal
```

El certificado lo obtuve de StarCom, pero me marca la leyenda "Este servidor no ha podido demostrar que es **Nombre_dominio;** el sistema operativo de tu ordenador no confía en su certificado de seguridad. 
E revisado con https://www.digicert.com/es/ayuda/ y me marca que el certificado esta bien instalado. Espero haberme explicado bien y les agradeceria mucho su ayuda!!

Comment: Tendras algun ejemplo ? porque se me esta haciendo imposible la conexion en https

Comment: El tema es que cuando tengas un nuevo certificado y lo configures, este se te vence a 90 días. Si la aplicación sigue arriba, cuando llegue ese momento tendrás que cambiarlo. Has pensado en cómo hacer que el archivo cambie dinámicamente?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno todo indica que el problema era el certificado, obtuve un certificado  para un mes (gratuito) y la misma configuracion y YA FUNCIONA!!. Ahora solo queda comprar un certificado por mas tiempo.

Comment: Gracias por aclararlo. Saludos.